# How can i organize my frame like this?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I want my frame to have 3 panels that will look like that

[image]

I'm a total newbie at `JPanel` and i cant organize it, so if someone can help i'd appreciate it

Comment: Read up on LayoutManagers: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by having a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).  While you could use a `GridBagLayout`, you could simply use a series of compound containers using `BorderLayouts`

For example...

```
JPanel left = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
left.add(new TestPane(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
left.add(new TestPane());

JPanel main = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
main.add(left);
main.add(new TestPane(), BorderLayout.EAST);
```

[image: SimpleLayout]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JPanel left = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                left.add(new TestPane(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
                left.add(new TestPane());

                JPanel main = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                main.add(left);
                main.add(new TestPane(), BorderLayout.EAST);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(main);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @noam Glad it could help

Answer (score 0):

You must use a [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html).

There's plenty of information about SWING and layout manager on the net.

Check

- [A visual guide to LayoutMangers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- [Using Layout Mangers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Or just google for SWING and layout.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `BorderLayout` to arrange my panels. I set up 3 panels: east (width 100px), north(height 100px) and center:

```
public class Frame1 extends JFrame {
  BorderLayout borderLayout1 = new BorderLayout();
  JPanel jPanelEast = new JPanel();
  JPanel jPanelCenter = new JPanel();
  JPanel jPanelNorth = new JPanel();
  BorderLayout borderLayout2 = new BorderLaout();
  JPanel jPanelCentral = new JPanel();

  public Frame1() {
    try {
      jbInit();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  void jbInit() throws Exception {
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(borderLayout1);

    jPanelEast.setBackground(Color.red);
    jPanelEast.setForeground(Color.black);
    jPanelEast.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
    jPanelEast.setOpaque(true);
    jPanelEast.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 10));

    jPanelCenter.setLayout(borderLayout2);

    jPanelNorth.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    jPanelNorth.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
    jPanelNorth.setOpaque(true);
    jPanelNorth.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 100));

    this.getContentPane().add(jPanelEast, BorderLayout.EAST);
    this.getContentPane().add(jPanelCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jPanelCenter.add(jPanelNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    jPanelCenter.add(jPanelCentral, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame1 frame1 = new Frame1();
  }
}
```